# MYSQL: How to avoid inserting duplicate records?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join, crud

I am making an insert statement as following:

```
Insert into table2 (host, ip, domain, statusnew) 
select hostname, ip, domain, "True" from table1 t1, table2 t2 
where t1.status = "Done"
and t2.statusnew not regexp "True"
limit 10
;
```

I have added the statement  `t2.statusnew not regexp "True"` just to make sure that there is no duplicate insertion. But, it is adding duplicate rows.

How to make sure that there is no duplicate entries?

Comment: I think this maybe the reason of duplicate entries from table1 t1, table2 t2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2
  (id, name)
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.name
  FROM TABLE_1 t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM TABLE_2 t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id)
```

Comment: I am not inserting any `id` value. The PK is created automatically. Can you help how I can use `Not Exists` in my above query?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use IGNORE keyword to avoid duplicate record.
Like:

- INSERT IGNORE INTO employee (last_name, first_name) VALUES( 'Rinku', 'Gohel');